# FreeBSD and i915KMS result in black screen

Tags: freebsd, video, resolution, intel, i915

I only had `800*600` resolution when I installed `xorg` and `openbox`. I did some digging and I found out for `Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller` I have to active it. so I added this to my `/etc/make.conf`

```
 WITH_NEW_XORG=true
 WITH_KMS=true
```

and update my base system and also `portmaster -af` to update all my packages.
That update worked; **but now every time I am trying to do `startx` or `X -configure` , my monitor goes black and and its power light start blinking like it is on standby.
further investigation showed this black screen happens whenever I do `kldload i915kms`.
Now i am out of idea and options.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://wiki.freebsd.org/Intel_GPU or do you think it has no related information?

Comment: @peterph ;I followed exactly that page. But a it mentions the **black screen** and offer the solution by telling to use `startx`. but the problem arises by `startx`.

Comment: OK, sorry. By the way, on Linux I sometimes use `startx & sleep 20; chvt 1`, which in some cases puts you back to text console. Alternatively you can ssh to the machine and see what is going on there.